# Change position of "All Programs" button on start menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, start-menu

I currently have my taskbar set to the left side of my screen (which gives more vertical screen estate on a wide screen monitor)

One minor annoyance is that the start button is now in the top left corner, not a problem in that, but when you click on it and the popup menu appears, the "All Programs" link is now at the bottom of the menu. This leads to excessive mouse movement.

Is there an easy way to move the "All Programs" link so that it appears at the top of the start menu?

Comment: Use the Windows key to open the Start menu. I don't know of any way to change the position, sorry.

Comment: [The Windows 10 version of this question is here](http://superuser.com/q/1046377/91971).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to change the order of items on the start menu.

However, the for pay version of [Vista Start Menu](http://www.vistastartmenu.com/) appears to offer this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Vista Start Menu looks like an interesting program, and I know some people that would like this but I actually like the standard Windows 7 start menu, it just takes a bit of housework to keep it tidy.